# c# console app using thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, console-application

I have a console app. I need to implement a **do while** that loop infinitely and a thread that at every 3 seconds returns a list of items from a page. How can I do that? I have a methold called getId( string URL) . how do I implement the thread in the **do while**?

Comment: Are you asking how to create the thread?

Answer (score 1):

Using [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class:

```
string url = "www";            
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
timer.Elapsed += (o, e) => this.GetId(url);
timer.Start();
```

> Timer is designed for use with worker threads in a
>   multithreaded environment. Server timers can move among threads to
>   handle the raised Elapsed event, resulting in more accuracy than
>   Windows timers in raising the event on time.
>
> The Timer component raises the Elapsed event, based on the value of
>   the Interval property

Answer (score -1):

I would not use a timer - what happens if the item retrieval takes longer than three seconds?

Can you live with a sleep(3000) loop?

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: I belive case you've mentioned is design problem rather a timer specific. If such a case is real - obviously solution would be more complex rather that simply `timer.Elapsed +=... and timer.Start()`. For such case it makes sense to run a separate thread with Thread.Sleep + some kind of synchronization handle like AutoReset/ManualReset event

Comment: @sil - yes, that is one solution if the 3 seconds is a lock, which is why I asked the question 'Can you live with a sleep(3000) loop?'.  If not, then a simpler solution is to store the tick count before the attempted retrieval, subtract it from the tick count after the retrieval and use this value for the sleep() parameter.  That would give retrieval every 3 seconds unless the retrieval takes longer than 3 seconds, in which case then next retrival would start immediately after the last - no extra thread, timer, sync etc. needed, (account for tick rollover).